# Insert statement to PostgreSQL from Java application taking too long

Tags: java, postgresql, performance, insert

**Problem Statement**
I have java application which is supposed to insert records into PostgreSQL However the insert process is taking way too long ( approx 20 minutes for 5000  records). We are migrating from IBMDB2 to PostgreSQL and the same query ( with DB2 specific syntax) takes  few seconds to complete in DB2. Seems something is wrong with the query since we haven't observed any performance issues.

**The query format is as:**

```
INSERT INTO CI_DATA_SERVER (
COST_CENTER,MANAGED_BY,DMODEL,DVERSION,DPRODUCT,DATASET,STATUS,DU,IDENTITYKEY,DESCRIPTION,COMPANY,LOCATION,OWNED_BY,CLASSTYPE,CRT_ON,NE_STATUS,"type",KEY1,KEY2,KEY3,
KEY4,KEY5,KEY6,KEY7,KEY8,KEY9,KEY10,IDENTIFIER1,IDENTIFIER2,DISC_ON,DISC_BY,MOD_BY,CRT_BY,PARENTID,MOD_ON,NPRODUCT,NMODEL,NVERSION,MERGEDDATASETNAMES,
MERGEDDATASETCOUNTS,HW_TYPE,ASSET_CUSTODIAN_NAME,ASSET_CUSTODIAN_EMPLOYEEID,MODEL_NUMBER,STATE,CITY,MAC_ADDRESS,SEAT_NUMBER,RACK_NUMBER,ODC,MODEL_NAME,
"floor",DEPARTMENT,DATA_CENTRE_CLOSET,BUILDING,ASSET_USER,ASSET_TYPE,ASSET_CATEGORY,ASSET_AT_HCL_PREMISE,AMC_STATUS,AMC_START_DATE,AMC_END_DATE,ACCOUNT_NAME,
PASSWORD_LAST_SET_ON,HW_LAST_SCANNED_ON,SW_LAST_SCANNED_ON,USER_LAST_LOGGED_ON,IN_HCL_SCOPE,DATACENTER,REGION,COUNTRY,OSI_CLUSTER_NAME,OSI_STATUS_CHANGED_ON,
OSI_PORTFOLIO_ID,ENVIRONMENT,PROCESSOR_CORES,METALLIC,SITE_TYPE,OWNERSHIP_TYPE,OS_RELEASE_VERSION,OS_SERVICE_PACK,OS_VERSION,OS_TYPE,PROCESSOR_MEMORY,MANUFACTURER,
PROCESSOR,OS_NAME,CORES,IP_ADDRESS,SERIAL_NUMBER,IS_VIRTUAL,FQDN,ASSET_TAG,HOSTNAME,AMC_SUPPORT_VENDOR,SUB_STATUS,DISC_SPACE,MEMORY,ERROR_MSG,JOBHISTORYID,
PROCESSING_STATUS,MATCHING_OTHER_IDENTITY_KEY,MERGEPARENTIDS,DELETED_FLAG,TARGET_DS_NAME)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

**PostgreSQL environment details**

- Hosted on AWS RDS
- version 13.3
- Instance type: (db.m5. large with 2vCPUs, 8GB RAM, 4750 MBPS with 3000 provisioned IOPS).

**Key points:**

1. The batch size is 600 records.
2. There is no data type casting required in this query as data value is compatible with type so there is no bottleneck of type casting.
3. There are no triggers in the table.
4. There are no multi-value inserts.

**What I have tried besides finetuning the query-**
•   Drop indexes before starting the import, re-create them afterwards.
•   Tried inserting data on a dedicated postgres instance
•   tried increasing batch size to 2000 records

[Monitoring snapshot of PostgreSQL performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlHVk.png)

Comment: Are all statements in a single transaction? Did you test if the I/O system is working fine? Use auto_explain to capture a slow execution plan and add it to the question.

Comment: Your monitoring shows the slow statement to be a select, not an insert.